# I need help downloading Tor browser

Tags: help, ios

I have been able to download Tor's main site but I can't get the Tor browser. I'm trying to do this with an iPod touch. Can anyone help me please

Comment: I have used the torproject's "Orbot" on my iphone. It may work on iPod,not sure though.

Comment: Mike Tigas develops the Onion Browser for iPhone and iPad: https://mike.tig.as/onionbrowser/ However I don't think it will work on iPod.

Answer (score 1):

The Tor Browser is not an application for an iPod touch. The applications on Tor's website that are available currently are only supported by Windows Computers, Apple Computers, and Linux Computers. There are applications for Android on the Google Play Store that are really well done as well. I am not familiar with any apps on the App Store that will connect you to Tor.